# How to access a nested object inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm trying to iterate through a object which is inside a function, I have tried different ways but I can't make it work.

```
function x() {
    let y = {
        "Caspian Sea": 560,
        "Tarn Hows": 53,
        "Crater Lake": 324,
        "Lake Tanganyika": 803,
        "Lake Vostok": 546,
        "Lake Baikal": 897,
    };
}

Object.entries(x).forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(entry);|
})

//for (let entry of Object.entries( y )) console.log(entry);

//let entries = Object.entries(x)
//console.log(entries);
```

Comment: Return it from the function?

Comment: should be `Object.entries(y)`..why u put function inside Object.entries?

Comment: `y` is local to the function. Means you can't access it in outer scopes. One way is to return the object from the function and then use `x()` instead of `x`.

Comment: `y` is not going to be some property of the function object `x`. If you want to access `y` you need to have that code inside `x` or return `y` so that some execution of `x` will return it to your code. The only other option would be to parse the function body text manually which you probablly dont want to have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to access `y` outside of the function scope, you'll have to return it from the function. Then, in your `Object.entries` call, you'll have to actually call the `x` function to access the returned value.

```js
function x() {
    let y = {
        "Caspian Sea": 560,
        "Tarn Hows": 53,
        "Crater Lake": 324,
        "Lake Tanganyika": 803,
        "Lake Vostok": 546,
        "Lake Baikal": 897,
    };
    return y;
}

Object.entries(x()).forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(entry);
})
```